# Passing JSON object received asynchronously in block to an instance variable - using AFNetworking on iOS6

Tags: ios, json, serialization, nsarray, afnetworking

This code has the JSON but no matter what I do I haven't been able to figure out how to pass this JSON to an instance variable. Each time I set it to a variable and call that variable outside of this method its nil. So what I can gather is that the variable is called before the following async call returns.

So the question is what can I do to the following code so that I can extract the JSON value. Somewhere on the internet I read that I would need to pass it a block which would server as a call back on completion but I cannot figure out how to do that for the following code

```
 //Gets the JSON object that contains the entries from the server
 -(void)getEntriesFromServer 
 {
   NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

   [[appAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/entries"
                          parameters:nil
                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
    {
      NSLog(@" JSON array = %@",[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"entries"]);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
      NSLog(@" Json not received");
    }];
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `__block` to definition of an array e.g `__block NSArray* entriesArray;`
or make a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* entriesArray;
```

and change your code like this

```
[[appAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/entries"
                               parameters:nil
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
   {

     //NSLog(@" Json value received is : %@ ",[JSON description]);
     //NSLog(@" JSON array = %@",[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"entries"]);

     self.entriesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"entries"]];
     NSLog(@" JSON array from inside block = %@", _entriesArray);
     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@" Json not received");
    }];
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: Hi thanks but this is an async call and the JSON value is not returned right away. I was hoping for an answer that uses completion blocks. Is there any way you cuold show me that? thanks

Comment: I suppose, that your API client makes something like this:
`AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:yourSuccessBlockfailure:yourFailureBlock];

Comment: Yes the AFHTTPClient provided with the library does this in its implementation

Comment: yourSuccessBlock - it is a block, which will be called after successful completion of the request.
In this block you should parse answer from server. If answer from server is a JSON string, then you can use SBJSONParser to get JSON from it [SBJSON](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/).
So you code will be like [code](http://pastebin.com/bxLkwxb3)